# Can I store app properties without a file?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

I am familiar with the regular properties APIs for storing app-specific metadata to a file, but is there any way I can store App metadata within drive without linking it to a specific file?

I would prefer to store some configuration settings, but the only approach I've seen for this so far has been to create an actual file in GDrive (and hope the user doesn't delete it).

Is there a more stable approach?

Comment: what about final or contants variables?.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - Do you mean set CONST variables in the executing code?  I'll need these properties to be modifiable based on API return values, and retrievable from multiple separate launches of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a configuration in you [Application Data Folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) on Google Drive.

More infos in the actual documentations, but a quick explanation is that you can store files in an hidden folder visible only by your application (any application using the same api key share the same AppData folder).

For example I store a text file with the settings of an Android application, when the user installs it on a different device, the settings are downloaded to the new device.

The approach using a file to store settings let you keep track of the changes made on the configuration by using versions, but if you are more keen to use properties, you can still create an empty app.config file and store properties on it.

Comment: see also [drive.realtime.loadAppDataDocument](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime#gapi.drive.realtime.loadAppDataDocument).